# Wrapping models in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, ef-code-first

This question has originally started at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/62189/23107) so to avoid repetition I won't paste it all here. So after I received an answer to my initial question I have another question:
 How should I wrap my `business object` (which is used as an `Entity Framework Code First model`) so I can include some properties relevant only to the specific model and how should I expose it from my `ViewModel`? How do I save the changes back to the original `model`?

**EDIT:**
Still battling with this so I'm adding a small reproducible example:

```
//class used as an EF code first model
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ObservableCollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

`Person` is managed in a window called `PersonManagerWindow`

```
//view model for the PersonManagerWindow
public class PersonManagerViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    private string _personName;
    public string PersonName
    {
        get { return _personName; }
        set
        {
            _personName = value;
            SelectedPerson = null;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }


    private Person _selectedPerson;
    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get { return _selectedPerson; }
        set
        {
            _selectedPerson = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**My questions are:**

- Should the `SelectedPerson` expose a "real" Person object or should I
  create a view model for it?
- If `ViewModel` is preferred how should I use it in terms
  `Entity-Framework` access?

Comment: Have you considered a T4 Template ?

Comment: @Xaruth this is suitable for a `Code-First` scenario?

Comment: T4 Generation can be done when you want, so you execute it when there's a modification in your source or on pre-built.

Comment: @Xaruth tried to learn and use T4 templates over the last couple of days but I don't feel that comfortable with it. thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you must not change the original model

In one of my projects, I enhanced the original model with a T4 template. The classes are modified (by generator), but mot the source file.

For example, this is the **original code** :

```
public partial class ImprimanteSNData
{
    [T4Order(2)]
    private Boolean isConnected;

    [T4Order(0)]
    private List<String> printer;

    [T4Order(1)]
    private String serialNumber;
}
```

By T4, this class enhanced with :

**Generated code :**

```
[DataContract]
public partial class ImprimanteSNData : IExtensibleDataObject
{
    private ExtensionDataObject extensionDataObjectValue;

    public ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
    {
        get { return this.extensionDataObjectValue; }
        set { this.extensionDataObjectValue = value; }
    }

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public System.Boolean IsConnected
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.isConnected;
        }

        set 
        {
            this.isConnected = value;
        }
    }

    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public System.Collections.Generic.List<System.String> Printer
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.printer ?? new System.Collections.Generic.List<System.String>();
        }

        set 
        {
            this.printer = value;
        }
    }

    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public System.String SerialNumber
    {
        get 
        {
            return this.serialNumber == null ? String.Empty : this.serialNumber.Trim();
        }

        set 
        {
            this.serialNumber = value;
        }
    }

}
```

All this second part is fully generated from the first part. So, it's very simple to write new classes, and to modify getter fonctionnality.

**T4 Code :**

```
<#@ template language="C#" debug="true" hostSpecific="true" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Core.dll" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Xml.dll" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Xml.Linq.dll" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="System.Windows.Forms.dll" #>
<#@ Assembly name="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ import namespace="EnvDTE" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Diagnostics" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Xml.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #> 
<#@ import namespace="System.Reflection" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Runtime.Serialization" #>
<#@ import namespace="XXXXXXXXXXX" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Runtime.Serialization" #>
<#@ Assembly Name="$(ProjectDir)\bin\$(ConfigurationName)\FicheSignaletiqueViseoData.dll" #>
// T4Class : Génération des accesseurs de toutes les classes de FicheSignaletiqueViseoData
// pour les types non génériques et les classes, on rajoute une protection contre le null
// pour les String, on rajoute une protection contre le null et un Trim automatique
// Date de génération : <#= System.DateTime.Now.ToString() #>
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

<#   
    const String BusinessEntityNamespace= "XXXXXXXXXXX";

    WriteLine("namespace {0}", BusinessEntityNamespace);
    WriteLine("{");
    PushIndent("\t");

    String T4TemplatePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.TemplateFile);
    String dataContractSource = Path.Combine(T4TemplatePath, "DataContract");
    String[] sources = Directory.GetFiles(dataContractSource, "*.cs");
    IServiceProvider hostServiceProvider = (IServiceProvider)Host;
    EnvDTE.DTE dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)hostServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(EnvDTE.DTE));

    foreach(string file in sources)
    {
        EnvDTE.ProjectItem projectItem = dte.Solution.FindProjectItem(file);

        FileCodeModel fileCodeModel = projectItem.FileCodeModel;

        if (fileCodeModel != null)
        {
            foreach (CodeElement codeElement in fileCodeModel.CodeElements)
            {
                if (codeElement is CodeNamespace)
                {
                    CodeNamespace nsp = codeElement as CodeNamespace;
                    foreach (CodeElement subElement in nsp.Children)
                    {
                        if (subElement is CodeClass)
                        {
                            CodeClass classe = subElement as CodeClass;
                            if (classe.Access == vsCMAccess.vsCMAccessPublic && classe.Name.StartsWith("T4") == false && classe.Name != "Important")
                            {
                                GenerateClassFromCode(classe);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    PopIndent();
    WriteLine("}");
#>


<#+  
    private void GenerateClassFromCode(CodeClass classToGenerate)
    {
        WriteLine("[DataContract]");
        WriteLine("public partial class {0} : IExtensibleDataObject", classToGenerate.Name);
        WriteLine("{");
        PushIndent("\t");

        WriteLine("private ExtensionDataObject extensionDataObjectValue;");
        WriteLine(String.Empty);
        WriteLine("public ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData");
        WriteLine("{");
        PushIndent("\t");
        WriteLine("get { return this.extensionDataObjectValue; }");
        WriteLine("set { this.extensionDataObjectValue = value; }");
        PopIndent();
        WriteLine("}"); 
        WriteLine(String.Empty);

        List<Tuple<string, Int16>> checkOrder = new List<Tuple<string, Int16>>();

        List<CodeVariable> listVariable = new List<CodeVariable>();
        List<CodeEnum> listEnum = new List<CodeEnum>();

        foreach (CodeElement elem in classToGenerate.Members)
        {
            if (elem is CodeVariable)
            {
                listVariable.Add(elem as CodeVariable);
            }

            if (elem is CodeEnum)
            {
                listEnum.Add(elem as CodeEnum);
            }
        }

        foreach(CodeVariable variable in listVariable)
        {
            if (variable.Access == vsCMAccess.vsCMAccessPrivate)
            {
                // attributs
                foreach (CodeAttribute attribut in variable.Attributes)
                {
                    Int16 order = getPropertyOrderFromCode(attribut);
                    if (order >= 0)
                    {
                        if (checkOrder.Where(c => c.Item2 == order).Count() > 0)
                        {
                            WriteLine("// Ci dessous, erreur de compilation voulue. Veuillez corriger et recompiler.");
                            WriteLine("ERROR : Dans la classe " + classToGenerate.Name + ", doublon sur le T4Order " + order + " (utilisé par " + checkOrder.Where(c => c.Item2 == order).First().Item1 + ")");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            WriteLine("[DataMember(Order = {0})]", order);
                            checkOrder.Add(new Tuple<string, Int16>(variable.Name, order));
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Write("[" + attribut.FullName);
                        if(attribut.Children != null && attribut.Children.Count > 0)
                        {
                            TextPoint start = attribut.Children.Cast<CodeElement>().First().GetStartPoint();
                            TextPoint finish = attribut.GetEndPoint();
                            String allArguments = start.CreateEditPoint().GetText(finish);
                            Write("(" + allArguments);
                        }

                        WriteLine("]");   
                    }                   
                }

                // variable
                string propertyTypeStr = variable.Type.AsFullName;
                Type type = Type.GetType(propertyTypeStr);

                WriteLine("public {0} {1}", propertyTypeStr, MakeUpper(variable.Name));
                WriteLine("{");
                PushIndent("\t");

                    // getter
                    WriteLine("get ");
                    WriteLine("{");
                    PushIndent("\t");
                        if (propertyTypeStr == "System.String")
                        {
                            WriteLine("return this.{0} == null ? String.Empty : this.{0}.Trim();", variable.Name, propertyTypeStr);
                        }
                        else if (listEnum.Select(e => e.FullName).Contains(propertyTypeStr))
                        {
                            WriteLine("return this.{0};", variable.Name);
                        }
                        else if (type == null || ((type.IsGenericType || type.IsClass)))
                        {
                            WriteLine("return this.{0} ?? new {1}();", variable.Name, propertyTypeStr);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            WriteLine("return this.{0};", variable.Name);
                        }

                    PopIndent();
                    WriteLine("}");     
                    WriteLine(String.Empty);

                    // setter
                    WriteLine("set ");
                    WriteLine("{");
                    PushIndent("\t");
                        WriteLine("this.{0} = value;", variable.Name);
                    PopIndent();
                    WriteLine("}"); 
                PopIndent();
                WriteLine("}"); 
                WriteLine(String.Empty);
            }
        }

        PopIndent();
        WriteLine("}");
        WriteLine(String.Empty);
    }

    private Int16 getPropertyOrderFromCode(CodeAttribute member)
    {
        if (member != null)
        {
            if (member.FullName == typeof(T4Order).ToString())
            {
                return Convert.ToInt16(member.Value);
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    private String MakeUpper(String name)
    {
        return name.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + name.Substring(1, name.Length-1);
    }
#>
```

I used  also a attribute (tricky thing, I can flag the private properties in original code to make DataOrder on public properties in generated code)

```
public class T4Order : Attribute
{
    private Int16 order;

    public T4Order(Int16 o)
    {
        this.order = o;
    }

    public Int16 Order
    {
        get { return this.order; }
        set { this.order = value; }
    }
}
```

This is only an example, but it show that it is possible to do a lot of thing with T4, without modifying original code.